# How check if html5 form validation is complete

Tags: jquery, forms, html

I have a form which am using html5 to validate for email and required fields.
The form is to be submitted via ajax.
How do i determine that the form passed validation before i allow to form to submitted via ajax.

This is my html:

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="comment_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?=$post->ID ?>" />
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required="required">

  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" required="required">


  <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  <textarea name="comment" required="required" >
  </textarea>


  <label for="submit"></label>
  <button type="submit"class="button green meduim" id="comment_btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my jquery

```js
$("#comment_btn").click(function(e){
  //the request url
  var url = site_url+'comments/post_comment';
  //cross site request forgery token
  var xtoken = $("input[name='xtoken']").val();
  //post data
  var dataObj = {
    "name":$('#name').val(),
    "email":$("#email").val(),
    "comment":$("#comment").val(),
    "post_id":$("input[name='post_id']").val(),
    "xtoken":xtoken
  };
  //dim form
  $('#comment_form').addClass('dim');
  //make request
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    data:dataObj,
    dataType:'json',
    error:function() {},
    success:function(resp) {
      if(resp.status == "ok")
      {
        $('#comment_form').removeClass('dim');
      }else {
        alert("An error was encountered");
      }
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there a way to determine if the form is validated?

Comment: You can just say `required` instead of `required="required"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the validator's [form()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form) function, e.g.

```
var validator = $("#comment_form").validate(options);
if (validator.form()) {
    // submit with AJAX
}
```

Answer (score 42):

Don't bind to the click event of the submit button simply bind to the submit event of your form:

```
$('#comment_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //submit via ajax
});
```

Comment: Short, concise, to the point = elegant. This is the best answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best not to rely on the browser to validate your data, sure using [required](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-required-attribute) and [pattern](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-pattern-attribute) is cool and all but i wouldn't depend on it.

Write your own validation into your javascript before the data is sent off to your URL. You could do this with a bit of [Regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) or you could use many of the jQuery validation plugins available out there such as [h5validate](https://github.com/dilvie/h5Validate) or [Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Answer (score 0):

You can register to standard form 'onsubmit' event which will be fired if form has successfully passed validation and is being submitted.

```
document.getElementById("comment_form").onsubmit = myPassedValidationHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **better way I use and work** for me is this one:

**JQuery**:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#address-form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // submit via Ajax
});
```

This way is for **prevent submit and send form via ajax**, regards!

Answer (score 0):

It's been long, but here is my aproach to this kind of situation. Especially when i prefer to use AJAX with native HTML validation.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", checkIfValid);
const checkIfValid = {} => {
  if(document.getElementById('myForm').checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Do some AJAX stuff;
    }
}
```

> PS: If `event.preventDefault()` is used outside `if` clause, it doesn't do the trick.